# Can't save data using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to save the data to DB using SQLite. But an error occurs in the following code of SaveSQLite class.

I write InsertData() in Fragment1 class, could be saved successfully. However, an error has occurred when I write InsertData() in SaveSQLite class.

What should I do to run the InsertData() in SaveSQLite class?

```
MySQLiteOpenHelper helper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceBundle){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        Button btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bt_save);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText et_name = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_name);
                String name = et_name.getText().toString();
                // Insert Data
                SaveSQLite sqlite = new SaveSQLite();
                sqlite.InsertData(name);  //(Fragment1.java:37)
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

SaveSQLite.java

```
public class SaveSQLite extends Activity {
    public SaveSQLite() {
    }
    public void InsertData(String name){
        MySQLiteOpenHelper helper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();  //(SaveSQLite.java:21)
        db.beginTransaction();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name", name);
        db.insert("user", null, cv);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
        helper.close();
    }
}
```

MySQLiteOpenHelper.java

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final static String DB_NAME = "sample.db";
    private final static int VERSION = 1;

    public MySQLiteOpenHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
            "name TEXT)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(9206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(9206): Process: com.example.sample, PID: 9206
E/AndroidRuntime(9206): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:256)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at com.example.sample.SaveSQLite.InsertData(SaveSQLite.java:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at com.example.sample.Fragment1$4.onClick(Fragment1.java:37)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: >Instead, you should pass a Context (e.g., the calling Activity) in its constructor. Please detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `SaveSQLite sqlite = new SaveSQLite();` as

```
SaveSQLite sqlite = new SaveSQLite(getActivity());
```

in Fragment1

&

Change code of your class "SaveSQLite" like ,

```
public class SaveSQLite {
    private Context mcontext;
    public SaveSQLite(Context context) {
      this.mcontext = context;
    }
    public void InsertData(String name){
        MySQLiteOpenHelper helper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(mcontext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();  //(SaveSQLite.java:21)
        db.beginTransaction();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name", name);
        db.insert("user", null, cv);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
        helper.close();
    }
}
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use This Method To Add Data in Your Database Table.

```
// table name
private static final String YOUR TABLE NAME = "name";

public void addItem(String title, String description) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_TITLE, title); // news title
    values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description); // news
                                                // description

    db.insert(YOUR TABLE NAME, null, values);
    db.close();

}
```

Hope it helps you to solve your problem.